# Converting complicated SQL query into Rails ActiveRecord expression

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following SQL which I cannot seem to express using active record objects/methods in Rails.

```
SELECT users.*, count(followings.user_id) as expr1 FROM users 
  inner join followings on id = follows where id in (2,3,4) 
  group by followings.follows order by expr1 desc;
```

Obviously, [2,3,4] is replaced with any array of Ids.

This query executes no problems, and gives the results I want. But I am having great difficulty in how to go about expressing it the 'ActiveRecord' way.

How do I get my Users model to order by the number followers?

Comment: How are your models setup? (I'm asking for the relationship between the models, I assume a User has_many: followings, and a Following belongs_to: user ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this query:

```
User.select("users.*, count(followings.user_id)").joins(:followings)
.where("users.in (?)", [2,3,4]).group_by("followings.follows")
```

If you are getting other errors please let me know.

Comment: This is a good solution, (and there is an error in the where condition) - but it doesn't group properly nor play nicely with will_paginate.

I have instead had to use find_by_sql to make it behave properly.